# from list of tuples, get tuple closest to a given value

Tags: python, list, tuples, coordinates

Given a list of tuples containing coordinates, I want to find which coordinate is the closest to a coordinate I give in input:

```
cooList = [(11.6702634, 72.313323), (31.67342698, 78.465323)]
coordinate = (11.6702698, 78.113323)
takenearest(myList, myNumber)
...
(11.6702634, 72.313323)
```

Please let me know...

Comment: show your attempts..

Comment: It will help us give you a better answer if you show us what you've already tried. This way you won't say "Oh, thanks for trying to help, but I already tried that. "

Comment: How do you define distance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your data

```
cooList = [(11.6702634, 72.313323), (31.67342698, 78.465323)]
coordinate = (11.6702698, 78.113323)
```

the shortest Pythonic answer is:

```
nearest = min(cooList, key=lambda x: distance(x, coordinate))
```

with a function `distance(a, b)` returning the distance between the points `a` and `b` as a float, which you have to define yourself.

Now you have to decide how you calculate the distance: using simple `a² + b² = c²`, some geographical formula or a dedicated library.

Comment: There is an error:NameError: global name 'distance' is not defined

Comment: @Jothimani Please don't tell me you can't google `python points distance`

Comment: @Jothimani: You could use the [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) function to calculate the Euclidean distance. Note however that you don't really need the actual distance to find the `d1 < d2` closest—a common speed-up when doing distance comparisons is to use the distances _squared_ which avoids the need to take a computationally-expensive square-root to obtain an actual distance. This is because for positive numbers, if `d1 < d2` then `d1² < d2²` will also be true.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you want the coordinate from the list that has the least distance to the given coordinate. That means you can just loop through the list like that:

```
def closest_coord(list, coord):
    closest = list[0]
    for c in list:
        if distance(c, coord) < distance(closest, coord):
            closest = c
    return closest
```

To calculate the distance between two variables, just use Pythagoras.

```
def distance(co1, co2):
    return sqrt(pow(abs(co1[0] - co2[0]), 2) + pow(abs(co1[1] - co2[2]), 2))
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: You can skip the `sqrt` for speed.

Comment: I know, for this case that will work, however, the returned value wouldn't be the distance between the two points anymore. If @Jothimani needs special speed because their list is kinda huge (e.g.) they can just modify the code to make it fit their needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> min(cooList, key=lambda c: (c[0]- coordinate[0])**2 + (c[1]-coordinate[1])**2)
(11.6702634, 72.313323)
```

Comment: Ugh. Why not use some pythonic functions like `min` or `math.hypot`? No need to reinvent the wheel....

Comment: @sloth here it is. ;-)

Comment: You could also use `key=lambda c: math.hypot(c[0]- coordinate[0], c[1]-coordinate[1])`. Note that you also have a typo: `coordinate[0]` instead of `coordinate[1]`

Comment: Thanks for correction. I agree that math.hypot is better in some sense but sometimes I thought the math lib is really over-designed.

Comment: The Euclidean distance is not very useful with latitude & longitude. It's ok for small distances, but it doesn't work so well for larger distances &/or in regions near the poles.